# Visual Studio 2013 Solution level flags

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, c-preprocessor

I have 2 VS solutions. Both include the same project X. When I compile I want both solutions to trigger the #ifdef MYFLAG in a different way. So let's say I want solution A to have MYFLAG defined and solution B not to have it defined. If I do it at the project level like /D MYFLAG then both solutions will include this flag I want only one of them to do so.

Comment: Not an option.  You'll have to make do with /D $(SolutionName)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following directory structure:

```
test dir
    test.sln
    solution.h
    test dir
        test.vcxproj
test1 dir
    test1.sln
    solution.h
```

Both `test.sln` and `test1.sln` reference `test.vcxproj`.

File `test\solution.h`:

```
#pragma once
#define SOLUTION_NAME "test"
```

File `test1\solution.h`:

```
#pragma once
#define SOLUTION_NAME "test1"
```

In the project properties, additional include directories, add: `$(SolutionDir)`. Finally, project code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "solution.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << SOLUTION_NAME << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Build and run test.sln, it prints: `test`. Build and run test1.sln, it prints: `test1`. Place solution-dependent definitions to `solution.h` file according to your requirements.